# Licensing binaries of open source project with Apache License 2.0

Tags: licensing, binaries

I am writing an open source project licensed under Apache License 2.0, I wonder how can I license the precompiled binaries with the same license

Comment: Are you asking how you can distribute binaries that you have compiled, and have this distribution take place under the terms of Apache2?

Comment: Yes, but these binaries are precompiled from an open source project, so I want to know if and how I can distribute them under Apache license 2.0

Comment: What was the licence under which you received their sources?  Apache2 also?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have received the sources, those are mine too

Comment: I'm sorry, what?  The source which you intend to compile into these binaries - did you (a) write that yourself, from scratch, or  (b) is it either based on, or a copy of, some other sources which you received?  If (b), under what licence did you receive them?

Comment: I've written all the sources from scratch and want to license them and the binaries under Apache3

Comment: Assuming you mean Apache2, then what's the problem?  You do exactly what you've just said: however you choose to distribute them, you make it clear that the recipient is getting source and/or binaries under the terms of the Apache2 licence.

Comment: I wanted to know how to license it, i have to do it like the sources, with a file named LICENSE?

Comment: But you don't have to do it that way with the sources, either; it's merely conventional. You can do the same with the binaries, and package them with (eg) a tarfile containing a NOTICE file, or you can simply tell the recipient that they're getting a copy under the Apache2 licence.

Comment: What is a recipient?

Comment: The person who receives the copy of the binaries, and on whom the licence is binding.

Comment: Oh ok, but because it will have some dlls I will put a LICENSE file with the binaries in a tar or a zip

Comment: Seems reasonable.  Do you want me to write that up as an answer, or would you rather delete the question?

Comment: Thanks to [MadHatter](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/458/madhatter) now i know that I directly tell the recipient that is licensed under Apache2 or put a LICENSE file shipped with the binaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LICENCE file has no particular special meaning, though it is one conventional way of indicating applicable licence terms.  In this particular case, you're using the Apache2 licence, which accords special status to any `NOTICE` file that accompanies the download; so *if* you choose to use a licensing file in the tarfile that contains the binary and associated libraries, I'd call it `NOTICE`.

You could also use declarative text on the web page, if any, that distributes the binaries.  Or you could have a click-through for people downloading them.

Your obligations are to be clear and unambiguous about the terms on which you're letting people have source and/or binaries.  How you do that is up to you.